# How solve this equation

Tags: polynomials

Find the equation
$$x^5+10x^3+20x-4=0$$

My try:**I think this equation maybe take  Trigonometric functions**

Now I have solution:let

> $x=t-\dfrac{2}{t}$,then
>   $$x^5+10x^3+20x-4=(t-\dfrac{2}{t})^5+10(t-\dfrac{2}{t})^3+20(t-\dfrac{2}{t})-4=0$$
>   so
>   $$t^5-4-\dfrac{32}{t^5}=0$$

My question: why we take $x=t-\dfrac{2}{t}$

and This problem have other solution? Thank you

Comment: Can you provide such a $t$? What is a $t$ that makes this a zero of the equation? Here is one value for $x= 0.19620865573750382297$, the other four are imaginary.

Comment: I have edit, Thank you

Comment: Because it gives you exact roots as http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=t%5E5-4-32%2Ft%5E5+%3D+0 (I am still not sure how they knew that)

Comment: We take $x=t-\frac 2t$ because it works.  I don't see how to guess that it will.  The lack of even power terms suggests a substitution like that.  You could try $x=t-\frac at$, do the evaluation, and see what value of $a$ makes things cancel nicely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a thought how you can construct such a polynomial.

Consider the sequence of polynomials $P_n(x)$ with the property 
$$
P_n\left(t-\frac{2}{t}\right)=t^n+\dfrac{(-2)^n}{t^n}.
$$
It is easy to verify that
 
$P_0=2,\ P_1=x, \ P_2=x^2+4=xP_1+2P_0, \ P_3=x^3+6x=xP_2+2P_1$.

Then we immediately guess a recurrence relation for the polynomials $P_n$: 
$$P_n=xP_{n-1}+2P_{n-2}.$$
This relation can be easily verified 
(i.e. $\left(t-\frac{2}{t}\right)\left(t^{n-1}+\frac{(-2)^{n-1}}{t^{n-1}}\right)+2\left(t^{n-2}+\frac{(-2)^{n-2}}{t^{n-2}}\right)=\left(t^n+\frac{(-2)^n}{t^n}\right)$).

Then we easily compute $P_5(x)=x^5+10x^3+20x$ and therefore 
$$P_5\left(t-\frac2t\right)-4=t^5-\frac{32}{t^5}-4.$$
Using the polynomials $P_n$ you can produce many similar examples.