# Find all real roots of $x^5+10x^3+20x - 4=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find all real roots of the following fifth-degree equation

$$x^5+10x^3+20x-4=0.$$

In fact, the only one root is $\sqrt[5]8-\sqrt[5]4$. How to get that?

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: According to Matematica there is only one and it appears to be irrational. $x=0.19620865573750382...$

Comment: This equation has one real root, and it's not very nice.  Are you trying to find an approximation?

Comment: The result is $x=0.196209$

Comment: Maple gives
$x_0 \approx 0.1962086557375038229732578300768051056478145297847229605316974461169176963085374475908223396134722920$
If you want more digits, tell me. But this looks nothing like fun to me.

Comment: @B11b _please_ add the ellipsis. What you wrote is just wrong.

Comment: I think I have seen this exact equation on this site before, but I can't recall where. Putting $x=t-\frac{2}{t}$ gives a quadratic in $t^5$ if I remember correctly, which is then easily solved.

Comment: Aha I found it. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/545651/how-solve-this-equation

Comment: Note that it is at least easy to prove that there is only one root. It's derivative is strictly positive and clearly contains no horizontal asymptotes: from this it is simple to prove there can only be one real root. After that I can only imagine doing some nasty magic.

Comment: @TylerHolden: Or you can use [Descartes' rule of signs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes'_rule_of_signs).